# datasyslab geotools-wrapper cause NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_17 error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-sedona

When geotools-wrapper library loaded to spark-shell even only to the driver path, it will cause this error happen.

```
spark-shell --driver-memory 5G --executor-memory 5G --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 5 --conf 'spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/hadoop/segy_processor_libs/libs/geotools-wrapper-1.5.0-28.2.jar'
```

error:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_17
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getFinalModifiersFieldForJava17(ClosureCleaner.scala:424)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:402)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2531)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$map$1(RDD.scala:413)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:412)
  ... 47 elided
```

Seems this because geotools-wrapper library contain a different org.apache.commons.lang3 package. When geotools not included, JavaVersion.JAVA_17 is defined but when geotools included, JavaVersion.JAVA_17 be not defined.

```
scala> import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion
scala> JavaVersion.JAVA_17

And got:
<console>:24: error: value JAVA_17 is not a member of object org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion
       JavaVersion.JAVA_17
```

My question is, how can I solve this problem? Do I have to exclude org.apache.commons.lang3 when from geotools library? [not sure how to do it yet]

Another question is, why latest geotools-wrapper [1.5.0] still depend to sedona 1.3.1-incubating version [as on this pom https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datasyslab/geotools-wrapper/1.5.0-28.2/geotools-wrapper-1.5.0-28.2.pom], not to sedona 1.5.0. I wonder if this will be a problem if I use sedona 1.5.0 with geotools-wrappe-1.5.0, while geotools-wrappe-1.5.0 actually depend to sedona 1.3.1-incubating?

Note: this project is build using SBT

Comment: What build tool are you using? I recommend to run a dependency tree and review the dependencies. Then be aware that Spark comes with its own version of some libraries and you cannot upgrade them unless using stuff like "user classpath first" (look for this on a search engine).

Comment: SBT. Yes, the issue seems caused by dependency conflict.